# Cannot access controllers from outside object

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have some simple code here. It creates an **application** called 'MyApp' and defines a **controller** called 'MyController'. MyController is then passed in as a config into the application.

```
            function onDeviceReady() {

                alert('In onDeviceReady() function');

                MyApp.app.getController('MyController').somefunction();
//                MyApp.controller.MyController.somefunction()
            }

            Ext.application({
                name: 'MyApp',
                controllers: ['MyController']
            });

            Ext.define( 'MyApp.controller.MyController', {
                extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

                init: function () {
                    alert('Login controller');
                    onDeviceReady();
                },

                somefunction:function(){
                    alert ( 'some function callled' )
                }
            });
```

So far so good. Typical standard stuff. Now after the 'init' is called from MyController I call some outside method **onDevideReady**. From this method I want to access my controller again.

I have tried among others :

- MyApp.app.getController('MyController').somefunction();
- MyApp.controller.MyController.somefunction()

But none of these things seem to work... I am also using Extjs 4.1 which might be an issue. Basically I want to somehow access my controllers from inside my code (not necessarily from another controller)

Here is the fiddle of the problem :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jjh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No issue for me (once I move your controller/application around).

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    MyApp.app.getController('MyController').somefunction();
}

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        onDeviceReady();
    },

    somefunction: function() {
        alert('some function callled')
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: ['MyController']
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1jk7

Nont really the way I would do things, however. I'd rather not have a global function and have it peer deep into my application. I'd rather have a singleton class that I would fire events on and so the controller would listen to those events then. Also, get off 4.1 :)

Comment: yes, i would love to get off Extjs 4. MVC architecture in 5+ is much much better :). The MVC architecture in 4 is truly awful.